# Receiving broadcasts and calling controller functions from isolated scope/directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr9c6/2/) exemplifying my situation.

First of all, is this the correct way to create directives with the received dimensions? 
Then, each directive should be isolated from the others.. hence I am using `scope: {}`.

The problem is calling functions that are in the controller.. and it seems it does not receive the broadcast either..

I am sure this is a trivial problem.. I am new to Angular :)

I have a page in which I load a number of components with ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="containerCtrl">
        <component ng-repeat='c in components' id="c.id" my-width="{{c.width}}" my-height="{{c.height}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
controller('containerCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.components = [{ id: "c1", width: 100, height: 100 },
                        { id: "c2", width: 200, height: 100 },
                        { id: "c3", width: 300, height: 100 }];

    //in the actual controller I am using a socket provider and doing
    //socket.forward([
    //        'initPage',
    //        'refreshPage'
    //    ], $scope);
    //simulating it with a simple broadcast here..
    $scope.$broadcast("onSomething", "");

    $scope.doSomething = function (data) {
        alert("doing something");
    };
}).
```

and the directive:

```
directive('component', function () {
        var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).
                resizable({
                    stop: function( event, ui ) {
                        scope.emitSomething(attrs.id, ui.position);
                    }
                });

            scope.$on('onSomething', function(res) {
                alert("onSomething!");
            });
        };

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div class="ui-widget-content" style="width: {{width}}px; height: {{height}}px;"></div>',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                width:'@myWidth',
                height:'@myHeight'
            },
            link : linkFn
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The controller executes before the link function, so your broadcast is being sent out too soon.  You can delay this using `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.$broadcast("onSomething", "");
});
```

To call a controller method from a directive with an isolate scope, you need to specify the method as an argument:

```
<component ng-repeat='c in components' id="c.id" my-width="{{c.width}}" 
 my-height="{{c.height}}" callbk="doSomething(data)">
```

and you need to use the `&` syntax in the directive:

```
scope: {
    width: '@myWidth',
    height: '@myHeight',
    emitSomething: '&callbk'
},
```

To pass parameters to that callback/controller function, you need to use the proper syntax: `scope.localDirectiveName({arg1: ..., arg2: ...})`.  In the fiddle, I only used one argument, and passed the two parameters in an array instead:

```
$(element).resizable({
   stop: function (event, ui) {
      scope.emitSomething({data: ["id", "position"]});
   }
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/vUgd6/)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect, thanks :) here is the working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dr9c6/6/ is it correct to say that the function declared in the <directive> tag is the function inside the controller,  while the other one that gets `{ data : }` is the function of the directive scope?

Comment: I am having a similar issue...broadcasting from controllers don't fire my events in directives...Timeout sometimes solves this but not always...Also, the app is quite heavy and I don't want to rely the fact that time would always be going to solve it...Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @ackuser, maybe you could have your directives send an initial "I'm alive" event up to the controller, and have the controller wait until it receives all of the required notifications before broadcasting back down.

Comment: Good point, I didn't have a thought about it...It seems to be a good solution although I suppose there should be an easy way to achieve that like priority in the directive or saying pls do this for me before the controller is loaded..I mean now I need to put a new broadcast or emit saying hi I am here and then get another $on in which I am broadcasting again ....still beginner in angular..Anyway thx ;)  +1